# What is the difference between Apache Commons Lang3 vs Apache Commons Text?

Tags: java, apache-commons, apache-commons-lang3

I am wondering **what is the difference between Apache Commons Lang3 (`org.apache.commons.lang3`) vs Apache Commons Text (`org.apache.commons.text`)?**

I saw many similarities between them.
For intance, they both have `StringEscapeUtils`:

- [org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html), which is Deprecated.
- [org.apache.commons.text.StringEscapeUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/apidocs/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html)

But I also saw many differences.
So which one should I use, Lang3 or Text?
Or what are the common use cases for each of these two?

Comment: Read the docs that you yourself linked to. The commons-lang3 version has been deprecated in favor of the commons-text version. I imagine that the other similarities you find will have similar deprecation reasons/messages.

Comment: Simple suggestion. Avoid using any deprecated API.

Comment: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/article3_0.html

Answer (score 5):

Well, the `text` method states

> This code has been adapted from Apache Commons Lang 3.5.

Looks like they simply plan on moving the method from one library to the other. You'd have to get the authors of that code to explain why.

However, worth pointing out that `lang3` is a compile dependency of `text`, therefore if you included `text`, you would have `lang3` anyway

https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/master/pom.xml#L61-L65

Comment: *".... therefore if you included text, you would have lang3 anyway"*.  Unless they decide to change the implementation!.  It is not a good idea to rely on undocumented dependencies.

Comment: @StephenC Where is it not documented? https://github.com/apache/commons-text/blob/master/pom.xml#L61-L65

Comment: The projects serve a different purpose - One is a dependency of the other. I don't contribute to Apache Commons, so I can't answer why they are copying code between projects

Comment: Since you asked.  It is not documented in the javadocs.  Do you think that they would hesitate to remove the "lang3" dependency from the POM file if they refactored `text`?  They are unlikely to consider the "edge case" of someone needing to use both APIs.  If an app programmer *does* want / need to use both `lang3` and `text` in his code, it is **prudent** to have explicit dependencies for both.

Comment: Reference: http://www.kyleblaney.com/maven-best-practices/ - "Used undeclared dependencies"

Answer (score 1):

Text utils in commons-lang3 are marked with deprecation and the [Javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/package-summary.html) points to commons-text

Comment: Consider editing your answer to address the OP's questions, which are "So which one should I use, Lang3 or Text? Or what are the common use cases for each of these two?"